# Showing Lemma's Fatou for functions not necessarily not negative.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $g$ integrable function on $E$ measurable set.
Let $(f_n)$ measurable functions and $|f_n|\leq g$ for all $n$.
Show that $\int_{E} \liminf f_n\leq \liminf \int_{E} f_n\leq \limsup \int_{E} f_n\leq \int_{E}\limsup f_n$.

I have a doubt.

with $(f_n+g)$ and Fatou, $\int \liminf (f_n+g)\leq \liminf \int (f_n+g)$

Now. Is it true that $ \liminf (f_n+g)= (\liminf f_n)+g$? I ask this, well, if it's true then $ \int \liminf (f_n+g)= \int [(\liminf f_n)+g]=\int\liminf f_n+\int g$ and $\liminf \int (f_n+g)=\liminf (\int f_n+\int g)=\liminf \int f_n+\int g$  and so 
$\int \liminf f_n+\int g\leq \liminf \int f_n+\int g$, and $g$ integrable, implies $\int \liminf f_n\leq \liminf \int f_n$

Comment: for a proof of $\liminf (f_n+g)= (\liminf f_n)+g$ see proposition 2.3 in [this paper](http://people.math.aau.dk/~cornean/analyse2_F14/limsup-liminf.pdf). Now choose $b_n=b$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ and you get the stated equality

Comment: proposition 2.3. Also works with secuenque of functions?

Comment: it is a point-wise sequence of functions, that is $\liminf (f_n+g)= (\liminf f_n)+g$ means that $\liminf (f_n(x)+g(x))= (\liminf f_n(x))+g(x)$ for any chosen $x\in E$